# Collections.unmodifiableList with custom objects, prevent state changes from outside

Tags: java

Let's say that there is a module. It contains a managing class `Foo` which contains a list of instances of class `Bar`.

```
public class Foo {

    private List<Bar> bars;

    public doStuff() { ... }
    private doOtherStuff() { ... }

    // method to get bars
    public List<Bar> getBars() { ... }
}
```

Then you have a class `Bar` with public getters to read the state of `Bar`. This class also contains mutators to change its state. These mutators can be both public and package level. The reason for a `public` mutator is that this modular class contains states which is used by other classes in **another** module (other package). So, each instances of `Bar` are mutable.

```
public class Bar {
    private int myInt; // simple example, but there are more attributes

    // constructor kept on package level
    Bar(...) { ... }

    // getters on public access 
    public int getMyInt() { ... }

    // change state
    public void doThis(int i) { ... }

    // update state
    void doThat(int j) { ... }
}
```

I have an issue, that when you want to display an overview of all instances from `Bar` (it has multiple attributes !) that external users ( the UI ) may not modify the state of this object. This is possible because there are some `public` mutators which is required by other modules.

After searching, it seems that i can use [`unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) to provide a read-only list. Like

```
public List<Bar> getBars() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(bars);
}
```

But this approach doesn't work because this ensures that the list *itself* is readonly. Which means that you cannot add elements to it. But, once you can retrieve an object, you still can modify it.

```
List<Bar> myBars = foo.getBars();
myBars.get(0).doThis(...);
```

the method `doThis()` is public accessible, so users may change the state while they aren't allowed to do that.

## So the question

(sorry for long intro)
Is there a good approach to solve this security problem ? Of course, i can make the method `doThis` non-public, but then i have to add methods in `Foo` so that `Bar` can be modified from other modules. In this situation, i have to do this thing with all public access methods in all modules (there are a lot ...)

I thought to combine the `unmodifiableList` method with `clone()` of Bar, like the next one

```
public List<Bar> getBars() {
    List<Bar> returnList = new ArrayList<Bar>(bars.size());
    for (Bar b : bars) {
        returnList.add(b.clone()); // clone an instance of bar
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(returnList);
}
```

This should work, but is this a good approach ? Especially when the list `bars` in the class `Foo` may be a huge list, which can slow down the runtime when trying to show the overview (cloning each instances).

Or is there a good alternative that i am not aware of ?

Comment: Instead of cloning `Bar`, better use a copy constructor or a different approach (find reasons here on StackOverflow). However, I would rather prefer wrapping your `Bar` objects with some unmodifiable wrapper, such as `UnmodifiableBar`.

Comment: @qqilihq : forgot that cloning vs copy reasons concerning custom objects. Thanks for that reminder. And can you give an example of such wrapper as answer ?  It can become an answer because that approach appears more promising.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding right, you want some other packages to be able to mutate but not others. Java doesn't have something like C++ `friend`, so you can't. You can either pick one or the other. Either accessible or not.

Comment: @KarelG So, what was your solution?

Comment: @qqilihq : Oh, completely forgot this question. I have solved it by making the accessors/getters (and other state checkers fe) only public. Other methods, even mutators/setters are kept internally. By this, objects outside the system couldn't manipulate the system objects.

Answer (score 0):

Make `Bar` implement an [Immutable Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_interface) providing the getters only, eg `ImmutableBar`. Pass the instances of `Bar` as `ImmutableBar`s to the GUI.

Comment: The wiki has mentioned that you can cast these to concrete class `Bar`. The user outside the system has just to find out the actual name of the class in order to modify it by a simple cast.

Comment: The user can also access the original `Bar` instances in the class where you are defensively copying them via reflection. There is no way to prevent the user from messing with something. Yet, defensive copies may make it harder. For defensive copies, use a copy constructor as suggested.

Comment: @KarelG Only if the name is accessible outside of the package. And it doesn't matter anyway because they can do anything they want with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying my comment from above, about the "immutable wrapper": The idea would be, to have an `ImmutableBar` implementation of your `Bar` interface, which intercepts modifications, such as:

```
/** Wraps a Bar, but prevents all modification operations. */
public final class ImmutableBar implements Bar {
    private final Bar wrapped;
    public ImmutableBar(Bar bar) {
        wrapped = bar;
    }
    @Override
    public int getMyInt() {
        return wrapped.GetMyInt();
    }
    @Override
    public void doThis(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Modifications are not allowed");
    }
    // etc.
}
```

**Caveat:** The modification is not prohibited at compile, but rather at runtime. However, you mimic the same behavior as with `Collections#unmodifiableList`, which you're already using (which also throws `UnsupportedOperationException` when trying to modify the collection). So this might be a viable solution for you.

Also keep in mind, that if you get hold of the wrapped `Bar`, modifications to those instances will still reflect on the wrapper. If you design an API, where you can control what instances to expose, this should not be an issue, if you take care.

**Suggestion:** I still would prefer a solution like suggested by @muued, which just provides the "read" operations within a common interface `Bar` and which has an immutable implementation (only implementing getters from `Bar`) and a mutable implementation (additionally providing mutators), `MutableBar` and `ImmutableBar`. Have a look at Apache Commons' [Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) for an example. This avoids any ambiguities during development, as immutable instances will simply not provide any modification API.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong, as far as my knowledge we don't provide any setter or modification of state method if creating immutable. and if dothis() method is doing the same, we can't make it immutable.

Comment: OP is not asking how to make `doThis` immutable but how to prevent users from calling it while returning `Bar` data.